# Image background doesn't fill in all divs

Tags: html, css

Background should shows in all divs but it's not visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/uxUqJ/1/

I need to my backgroud be shows in all divs. Background is defining in styles container div. Etc.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: wow... this question is not very well formatted.  It doesn't even form a cohesive inquiry.  Could you try making it into a question? Also, should it only show in the divs or the whole #content block?

Comment: Add overflow:hidden to ur #content.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add `overflow:auto;` to your css... I've also removed the quotes

```
#content{
    width:1049px;
    overflow:auto;
    background: #000 url(http://s1.wp.com/wp-content/themes/pub/dark-wood/images/postflowerback.png) ;
}
```

the Div currently has no height... however what do you want to do with the background regards repeating or position, here's a good reference point https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background

Comment: this is correct. when you float divs, the parent div doesnt stretch, but keeps a height of 0px. `overflow:hidden` might even be better, cause it removes the scrollbar

Comment: Good point regards the scrollbar! However the question was so poorly worded... but a great comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must specify `height` property and set `repeating` of background.

```
#content{
    width:349px;
    height: 700px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after the closing  for text3. This would then stretch the container divs around the elements even though they are floated.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the `#text` div.

**add the following styles:**

```
#text {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

#text:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear: both;
}
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/uxUqJ/13/

Answer (score 0):

You have your elements floated. You need to clear the float before closing the wrapper element in order to have the `#content` to grow normally:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/uxUqJ/7/) Example!

**CHANGE YOUR MARKUP TO THIS:**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="text">
    <div id="text_1">...</div>
    <div id="text_2">...</div>
    <div id="text_3">...</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>  <!-- Add this line -->
  </div>
</div>
```

*Additionally, you can remove the inline style and use a class.*

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to smart way

```
 <style>#content{ display:table;
    width:1049px;

    background: url("image_src") ;


}
#text{
  display:table-row;
    width:1049px;   
    padding-left:27px;
    padding-right:28px;}

#text_1,#text_2,#text_3{ display:table-cell;


    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 278px;
}#text_3{
    padding-right:40px;
}


</style>
```